# Is it bad to inherit in JavaScript by putting __proto__ to prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Here's one way to inherit `Child` from `Parent`:

```
function Parent(a)
{
  this.a = a;
}

Parent.prototype =
{
  constructor: Parent,
  parentValue: 123
};

function Child(a, b)
{
  Parent.call(this, a);
  this.b = b;
}

Child.prototype =
{
  constructor: Child,
  childValue: 456,
  __proto__: Parent.prototype
};

child = new Child(1, 2);

// Logs 1 2 456 123
console.log(child.a, child.b, child.childValue, child.parentValue);
```

Does this way of inheriting have drawbacks?

The rationale behind this is that I would like to add properties in bulk, e.g. `Foo.prototype = { a: 1, b: 2 }` and not `Foo.prototype.a = 1; Foo.prototype.b = 2;`, since the latter is too verbose.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: The main drawback is that `__proto__` is not supported in all browsers. Doesn't make sense to use it if you can achieve the same in a cross browser way.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it bad to inherit in JavaScript by putting `__proto__`?

Yes, because it isn't standard (*). Better use `Object.create`:

```
function Parent(a) {
  this.a = a;
}
Parent.prototype.parentValue = 123;
function Child(a, b) {
  Parent.call(this, a);
  this.b = b;
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
Child.prototype.childValue = 456;
var child = new Child(1, 2);
console.log(child.a, child.b, child.childValue, child.parentValue);
    // Logs 1 2 456 123
```

Or, if you want to support older browsers, instead of `Object.create` you can use

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

Note this approach will cause `Child` instances to inherit an undefined `a` property, but since you will create an own property using `Parent.call(this, a)`, it doesn't matter very much.

---

If you want to avoid verbose `Foo.prototype.a = 1; Foo.prototype.b = 2;`, you can use an `extend` function:

```
function extend(obj, props) {
    for(var i in props) if(props.hasOwnProperty(i))
        obj[i] = props[i];
}
extend(Child.prototype, {
    constructor: Child,
    childValue: 456
});
```

---

(*) ES6 includes `__proto__` in the (normative) annex for addtional ECMAScript features for Web browsers (note that the specification codifies what is already in implementations), but makes it optional if the ECMAScript host is not a web browser.
But MDN says that `__proto__` is deprecated.

Alternatively, ES6 introduces [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), which allows to change the prototype like `__proto__`, but MDN warns:

> Mutating the `[[Prototype]]` of an object, using either this method or
>   the deprecated `Object.prototype.__proto__`, is strongly discouraged,
>   because it is very slow and unavoidably slows down subsequent
>   execution in modern JavaScript implementations.

Comment: `__proto__` is in the ES6 draft tho

Comment: @CasperVonB According to MDN, ES6 introduces [`setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), and [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is deprecated.

Comment: Normative [draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-__proto___-property-names-in-object-initializers "Draft") allows it as part of the object literal enhancements

Comment: Its better to polyfil object.create in older browsers as Google closure has done for many years instead of setting Child prototype to an instance of Parent